# Rails web app ridiculously long loading time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Ruby on rails and my mentor just handed me a ruby on rails web application. It's fairly large but even then it's taking a ridiculously long time to load: **45 minutes!** By the time it hits 20 minutes the loading page of the app already displays an error saying *'Loading seems to be taking longer than usual, please refresh.'*

I'm running **rails 4.2.4** on a **linux server 14.04** (in Virtualbox). I access the website from my host machine (Windows 8). The rails uses **jbuilder 1.2** for building JSON.

From the development.log I gathered a ton of GET requests to load all the things. Here's a small selection of those:

```
Started GET "/assets/loader/loader.css?body=1" for 192.168.39.XXX at 2015-11-13 13:32:43 +0100
Started GET "/assets/reset.css?body=1" for 192.168.39.XXX at 2015-11-13 13:32:47 +0100
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.css?body=1" for 192.168.39.XXX at 2015-11-13 13:32:50 +0100
Started GET "/assets/site/form.css?body=1" for 192.168.39.XXX at 2015-11-13 13:32:53 +0100
Started GET "/assets/temporary.css?body=1" for 192.168.39.XXX at 2015-11-13 13:32:57 +0100
Started GET "/assets/vendor/spectrum.css?body=1" for 192.168.39.XXX at 2015-11-13 13:33:01 +0100
Started GET "/assets/general.css?body=1" for 192.168.39.XXX at 2015-11-13 13:33:04 +0100
```

As you can see, it takes each GET about 3-5 seconds, the log file is 2225 lines long from ONE load.

Is there any way to speed up the process?

EDIT: I copied the entire application to a different folder and tried running it from there. Loading time was down to only a couple of minutes. I still get the error *'Loading seems to be taking longer than usual, please refresh.'*, so it isn't fixed at all.

Comment: What else is being loaded? You probably don't have 2,000+ CSS files :-)

Comment: It loads a lot of javascript. I think I'm safe to say that 75% is either .js or .jstl files

Comment: Looks like a Virtualbox mounting file system issue to me. Try to debug this on 1 file, for example `/assets/reset.css`

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is but an earlier 'tryout' app I made last week did every GET in about 10ms.

Comment: How fast does the page load from with the VM. If the VM doesn't have a GUI, try loading the page with `curl`.

Comment: I tried using curl on the login page: 'Completed 200 OK in 667ms (Views: 665.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I removed the shared folder and installed samba on my linux machine and set that up for an anonymously shared folder. Now the folder is still shared with windows, so I can use it as I always have, but without the loading time issues or file system problems.

I've also followed this tutorial to set up apache with passenger:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6

Which decreased my loading time to 5 minutes total.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Virtualbox on Windows yet, but I had a similar problem with Virtualbox on MacOS. There was a [bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9069) related to VirtualBox shared folder. I switched to **NFS** sharing and the performance was greatly improved!

Sorry that I don't know how to configure NFS on Windows, but I hope this may help you.

**Update:**

Alternatively, I found a [workaround](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/351#issuecomment-1339640) for this issue. If you use `Nginx`(or `Apache`), just add this configuration option into your `nginx.conf` (or `apache.conf`) file.

In Nginx

```
sendfile off;
```

In Apache

```
EnableSendfile Off
```

Comment: Made the change in apache and it helps a little (down several minutes, huzzah!). I can't set up NFS on windows, as it's only included in the windows 8 Pro or Enterprise editions. Thanks for the help with apache though!

Comment: I tried something stupid, copying the project to a different folder in home and strangely enough loading time is **down 30 minutes**. I'll be looking into that folder thorougly.